# Splitting String in C using tabs, but also checking if it can be split through space

Tags: c, split, whitespace

I want to be able to split a string by tab and space at the same time. I am reading a struct from a file. I used the following code:

```
while (fgets(lyne,120,filehandle)) {
    printf("%s",lyne);
    item = strtok(lyne,"    ");
    record[reccount].n_adults = atoi(item);

    item = strtok(NULL,"    ");
    record[reccount].n_kids = atoi(item);

    item = strtok(NULL,"    ");
    strcpy(record[reccount].day,item);

    item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
    strcpy(record[reccount].weather,item);

    printf("%s\n",record[reccount].day);
         reccount++;
}

 /* Close file */

 fclose(filehandle);
```

However, sometimes instead of separating the the data through tab, some records have the data separated through space. How do i do a check in order to be able to handle those cases?

Comment: i managed to solve it by using strtok(NULL,"      .,?/ "), which consisted of all the possible delimiters. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read `man 3 strtok`.

The second parameter to that function is a string which may contain one **or more delimiters**.
To tokenize a string, call `strtok` once giving the string as the first parameter, and then call `strtok` with `NULL` as the first parameter while it returns non-`NULL`.

E.g. to "split" by tab *or* space characters:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *teststr = "test 123\t456 789";

int main() {
  char *str = strdup(teststr);

  char *tok = strtok(str, "\t ");
  while (tok) {
    printf("token: %s\n", tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL, "\t ");
  }
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ clang -o strtoktest strtoktest.c && ./strtoktest 
token: test
token: 123
token: 456
token: 789
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what type of spaces you want to break the string with. So to break string using tabs try you should use `\t`.

Example:
Replace `strtok(lyne,"    ");` by `strtok(lyne,"\t");`